# Storybook: can't change theming color on UI

Tags: javascript, angular, storybook, theming, angular-storybook

I'm trying to create my own theme in Storybook, and I'm following this: https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/configure/theming

For now I copied the the files from the sites, and that works, but I can't seem to change the colors to my preference. When I for example change color on appBg to green, it still stays as hotpink. Can someone help, have I missed a step?

manager.js

```
// .storybook/manager.js

import { addons } from '@storybook/addons';
import yourTheme from './YourTheme';

addons.setConfig({
 theme: yourTheme,
});
```

YourTheme.js

```
import { create } from '@storybook/theming';

export default create({
  base: 'light',

  colorPrimary: 'hotpink',
  colorSecondary: 'deepskyblue',

  // UI
  appBg: 'white',
  appContentBg: 'silver',
  appBorderColor: 'grey',
  appBorderRadius: 4,

  // Typography
  fontBase: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
  fontCode: 'monospace',

  // Text colors
  textColor: 'black',
  textInverseColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',

  // Toolbar default and active colors
  barTextColor: 'silver',
  barSelectedColor: 'black',
  barBg: 'hotpink',

  // Form colors
  inputBg: 'white',
  inputBorder: 'silver',
  inputTextColor: 'black',
  inputBorderRadius: 4,

  brandTitle: 'My custom storybook',
  brandUrl: 'https://example.com',
  brandImage: 'https://place-hold.it/350x150',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem! I had to update to the latest Storybook version and run with `--no-manager-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest version of the storybook. Tried to fulfill `--no-manager-cache`. But I can't change anything in the interface. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.2.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.13",
    "@storybook/theming": "^6.5.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^3.2.4",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^1.7.1"
  },
```

.storybook/main.js

```
const path = require('path')
const { mergeConfig } = require('vite')

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/react",
  "core": {
    "builder": "@storybook/builder-vite"
  },
  "features": {
    "storyStoreV7": true
  },
  async viteFinal(config) {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
        }
      },
  
      css: {
        postcss: null,
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            additionalData: `@import "../src/styles/styles.scss";`
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

.storybook/preview.js

```
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/
    }
  }
}
```

.storybook/BrandTheme

```
import { create } from '@storybook/theming'

export default create({
    base: 'light',
    brandTitle: 'My custom storybook',
    brandUrl: 'https://example.com',
    brandImage: 'https://place-hold.it/350x150',
    brandTarget: '_self'
})
```

.storybook/manager.js

```
import { addons } from '@storybook/addons'
import brandTheme from './BrandTheme'

addons.setConfig({
    theme: brandTheme
})
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33343712)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was solved by writing to package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "storybook": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && start-storybook -p 6006",
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).